# How to create array in plotting points

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I want to draw ellipse in `pb1` (picturebox) but the number of ellipse depends on what will the query will give. Usually, it is more than 1. I already have a code below but it only draw one ellipse.

I want to use array for this but i don't know how to. Any help/assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
Sub getdots()
    Try
        Call MyConnection()
        Sql = "select l.lot_no, l.lot_x, l.lot_y FROM lot_details AS l, area as a, type as t where l.type_no=t.type_no and t.AREA_NO=a.AREA_NO and a.AREA_NO=@Anum AND l.LOT_STATE='available'"
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(Sql, Con)
        With cmd
            .CommandText = Sql
            .Connection = Con
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Anum", frmvacantlots.cboareano.Text)
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If reader.Read Then
            Try

                x = reader.GetString(1)
                y = reader.GetString(2)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Con.Close()
End Sub


Private Sub pb1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles pb1.Paint
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, x - 5, y - 5, 10, 10)
    getdots()
End Sub
```

Comment: Store the result of `getdots` in a list of Point objects. Then in Paint execute the `FillEllipse` in a loop on every point in the list.

Comment: @Saragis i am not familiar with list of point objects and i don't get how when i tried to search it. can you help me? thank you so much

Comment: I added an example in an answer, please check it out

Answer (score 0):

Create a list to store all values:

```
Private points As New List(Of Point)
```

Read all points from your query:

```
While reader.Read
    Try
        x = reader.GetInt32(1)
        y = reader.GetInt32(2)
        points.Add(New Point(x, y))
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End While
```

For every values in *points*, draw like you already did for one value:

```
Private Sub pb1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles pb1.Paint
    points.ForEach(Sub(p) e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, p.X - 5, p.Y - 5, 10, 10))
    getdots()
End Sub
```